# How to send a zip file together with a message to the client in Django?

Tags: python, django, http, httpresponse

I have the following view function that creates a zip file and sends it to the client.
In addition to the zip file I also want to show the user a success message using django.contrib.messages.
My problem is that if I use HttpResponseRedirect client gets the message but not the zip file.
On the other side if I use HttpResponse client gets the zip file but not the message.
Is there any way to achieve both functionalities?

```
import os
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
...

def export_all(request):
    """
        Create a zip file and return it for download.
    """
    in_memory = StringIO()
    zip = ZipFile(in_memory, "a")
    exported_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%h-%Y')
    zip_file_name = 'my_files_' + exported_date

    a_to_export = A.objects.all().order_by('name')
    b_to_export = B.objects.all().order_by('name')

    # add relevant content to the zip file
    export_a(a_to_export, zip)
    export_b(b_to_export, zip)

    zip.close()

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/zip")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + zip_file_name + '.zip'

    in_memory.seek(0)
    response.write(in_memory.read())

    messages.success(request, 'All files exported successfully.')

    # If I use HttpResponseRedirect client gets the message but not the zip file.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))

    # If I use HttpResponse client gets the zip file but not the message.
    return response
```

Comment: Show the message and initiate a download through javascript

Comment: 1 - You could provide an intermediate page with links to download the file, in this case you need to write down to the disk, not memory.  2 - You could use django messages extends, it provides persistent messages but I don't know if it is compatible with recent Django versions (1.6 >).

Comment: further to @khaleel response... redirect to a download page and use ajax request for the download which could then display sucess message when complete.